# not able to integrate kendo ui in mvc4 with vs 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am Using VS 2012 and try to integrate Kendo UI in it.
I have install nuget "Kendo UI" and also give refrence in _Layout.cshtml

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.common.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.716/kendo.default.min.css")">
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/jquery.min.js")"></script>
```

When i am trying to take new view Kendo is not supportin

if i write in customerdetail.cshtml with following code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIDemo.Models.Customer>()
  .Name("grid")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource // Configure the grid data source
      .Ajax() // Specify that ajax binding is used
      .Read(read => read.Action("CustomerDetail", "Home")) // Set the action method which will return the data in JSON format
   )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(product => product.ProductID);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductName property
      columns.Bound(product => product.ProductName);
      // Create a column bound to the UnitsInStock property
      columns.Bound(product => product.UnitsInStock);
  })
  .Pageable() // Enable paging
  .Sortable() // Enable sorting
```

)

Error :- System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea tell me have alaready add reference in View's wen.config also
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download its installer(Latest Ver : `kendoui.aspnetmvc.2013.2.918.commercial.msi` ) & then install it. it's not done fully through nuget package so you get an error. (Bhai tamare kendo nu latest version nuget package mathi nai installer through download karvu padshe.)

Answer (score 3):

**Please see the documentation for initial setup guide - http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction.**

In your Web Project\Views\Web.config file check that Kendo.Mvc and Kendo.Mvc.UI are added as namespaces.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

In your Web Project\Web.config file you may need the below

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        ....
```

Also check your Project References so you have references to

```
Kendo.Mvc
System.Web.Helpers
```

Comment: Hi david i just install latest version and built its working but not able to find such namespace in view's web config as well as in main web.config.

Comment: if still it shows the same. please restart and Unload project and reload it again.